# Figures in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

There is something I don't get about figures in matplotlib.pyplot. When I call `plt.savefig()` for example, the pyplot library saves the image in a path that I give it as a parameter, however I don't have to give `savefig()` the actual important parameter `figure`, it just saves it without having the figure as an argument. How is this? Are figures in matplotlib some form of global singletons?

Comment: This question also applied to other functions than savefig(), it's just one example of many.

Comment: Yes.  Same thing applies to `plt.plot()` that almost everyone uses.  PyPlot builds up a global "canvas".